# Displaying an AJAX request on click even when the page changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Let me preface this question by letting you know that I am a complete AJAX/JSON noob. With that out of the way, I am trying to display an AJAX response in the sidebar on my website. So far I have it working flawlessly, however, now I would like to go a step further.

Right now I have the AJAX query bound to an on click event and it works great, but I would like for the information to stay in the DIV after the initial click of the button so that if the user navigates to other pages with the sidebar, the information will still be displayed without having to click the button again. I'm assuming this will require some sort of cookie, but maybe there's another way.

Here is my AJAX call:

```
$('#locSearch').click(function() {
    jQuery.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "html",
      url: "/search/locations/result.html",
      success: function(closestLoc) {

        jQuery('.locResult').html(closestLoc);

      } // end success

    }); // end ajax
});
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<div class="locinfo">
    <span id="locSearch" class="button">Click here to find the nearest location</span>
    <div class="locResult"></div>
</div>
```

Am I correct in assuming that this will require a cookie? Or is there a better/easier way, if so, what? Thank you!

Comment: `localStorage` is another option.

Comment: You could do it with iframes.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, `localStorage` can only store strings, correct?

Comment: Correct. But objects and arrays can also be stored as strings. so can html elements and functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What this is doing is setting SideBar in localstorage and on the page load it is checking to see if it is there.

```
if ( localStorage.SideBar == "Clicked" ){
    jQuery.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "html",
      url: "/search/locations/result.html",
      success: function(closestLoc) {

        jQuery('.locResult').html(closestLoc);

      } // end success

    }); // end ajax
}

$('#locSearch').click(function() {
    jQuery.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "html",
      url: "/search/locations/result.html",
      success: function(closestLoc) {

        jQuery('.locResult').html(closestLoc);

      } // end success

    }); // end ajax
    localStorage.SideBar = "Clicked"
});
```

Comment: yeah try that out tell me if it works. I haven't done too much with local storage, but something like this should work.

Comment: It worked perfectly on the first try, it is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

yes, you will need some way to persist the data, either a cookie, database or file on the server in which the site is hosted, or some sort of state if it were .net, php etc.